# how can i use amazon kindle on ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, wine, amazon, kindle

The version of my system is ubuntu 20.04 and of wine is wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)

``````bsh
Pictures screenfetch 
                          ./+o+-       liuqin19980818@liuqin19980818-ThinkPad-X2100
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-54-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 7h 1m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2300
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: zsh 5.8
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1440x1700
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 3.36.4
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Mutter
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Adwaita
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Yaru-light [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Papirus
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Roboto 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 61G / 143G (45%)
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: Intel Core2 Duo P8600 @ 2x 2.401GHz
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
                   ````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 2761MiB / 7858MiB
                          `oo++.
``````

and i can not use it with this picture
[image]

Comment: Can you use Kindle web reader instead of this app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used the native Kindle app but an alternative depending on what features you need may be to use Calibre which can read/write to Kindles.

Not sure what version is packaged with 20.04 but 20.10 comes with 4.99.12 (either from the software store or install via command line `sudo apt-get install calibre`).

5.5.0 is current latest version which you can download and do a binary install by following instructions on the developer site
https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

Answer (score 4):

Use [Kindle Cloud Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kindle-cloud-reader/icdipabjmbhpdkjaihfjoikhjjeneebd) (a web app that runs through Chrome) which allows you to access your Kindle books through Google Chrome browser.

You'll have to have Google Chrome installed, which you can download for Ubuntu [here](https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/).

Comment: BTW: Newer Amazon books no longer work with the Kindle Cloud Reader...

Comment: Agreed. Cloud reader is the ideal solution but for some reason it won't open a certain type of book I bought on the amazon store. It's a math book with a lot of code that I'd like to be able to copy paste, as well as read on a larger screen. It's strange it works with their apps but not the cloud reader, since you'd expect they use the same engine and since Amazon is after all a tech, and a cloud services company, but hey maybe someday it will.

Comment: Kindle Cloud Reader: "This item can only run on ChromeOS"...
but this works (as of Today):
https://read.amazon.com/kindle-library

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative in 01.2024, you can use: https://read.amazon.com/kindle-library instead.